# Cannot create a byte field in an Azure Table entity

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I've created an Entity class that extends [TableServiceEntity](http://dl.windowsazure.com/storage/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/TableServiceEntity.html). My class has a single field called "value" of type `Byte`:

```
public class TestEntity extends TableServiceEntity{

    public Byte value;

    public TestEntity(){
        super("some_partition","somekey");
    }
    public Byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://dl.windowsazure.com/storage/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/TableServiceEntity.html) for TableServiceEntity, `Byte` is one of the supported field types.

However when I try to store my entity, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type class java.lang.Byte is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.EntityProperty.<init>(EntityProperty.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.PropertyPair.generateEntityProperty(PropertyPair.java:271)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity.writeEntityWithReflection(TableServiceEntity.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity.writeEntity(TableServiceEntity.java:470)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.writeJsonEntity(TableEntitySerializer.java:317)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.writeSingleJsonEntity(TableEntitySerializer.java:411)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.writeSingleEntityToStream(TableEntitySerializer.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.insertImpl(TableOperation.java:389)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.performInsert(TableOperation.java:370)
...
```

The fault seems to be with the [EntityProperty](http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/EntityProperty.html) constructor (see [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/EntityProperty.java)), which doesn't seem to support `Byte` or `byte` types, only `Byte[]` and `byte[]`:

```
protected EntityProperty(final String value, final Class<?> type) {
   this.type = type;
   this.value = value;
   if (type.equals(byte[].class)) {
      this.getValueAsByteArray();
      this.edmType = EdmType.BINARY;
   }
   else if (type.equals(Byte[].class)) {
      this.getValueAsByteObjectArray();
      this.edmType = EdmType.BINARY;
   }
   ...
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a documentation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [documentation bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/31). As Herve Roggero noted, the [service model documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) states that Bytes aren't supported.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, the list of property types allowed for the Azure Table service does not include Edm.Byte, but does include Edm.Binary (which is byte[]). For a more in-depth understanding of the data types allowed and other limitations see [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx).